# What is the best word to describe items with specific uses. For example, a suction cup used to fix car dents

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to name categories on my online shop, I have a category for whimsical items, kids, etc. I'm trying to name a category for items that have actual day to day functionalities. For example, a suction cup used to fix car dents.

Thus:

1. Manual lint remover
2. Manual fruit juicers
3. Car back seat bag with pockets
4. Scratch removal device for cars...

These products, _____s, are mainly cool looking items, all with special functionalities.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Are you looking for a heading like "Day-to-day items" or a more specific heading like "Cups for car dent-pulling"? What are the criteria you will use to select an answer? Please have a look at our [checklist](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) for this sort of question.

Comment: Yes, a heading like day-to-day item closer to functional items.

Comment: Can you give more examples? The category might be too heterogeneous to admit a single name.

Comment: 1. Manual lint remover, 2. Manual fruit juicers 3. Car back seat bag with pockets 4. Scratch removal device for cars, etc. These products are mainly cool looking items with special functionalities.

Comment: In what ways would *useful items* fall short of your ideal? Are there nuances either present or absent?

Comment: "Specialized tools" or "rarely used"? Something like "Miscellany" or "Whimsy" would probably work if it's for your private use.

Comment: 'Accessories' would be used for fairly well defined sets (so wall-mounted can openers /  manual fruit juicers are kitchen accessories while 'car back seat bag with pockets' /  scratch removal device for cars' are car accessories). // [Is there a noun for a small but very useful thing?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/364740/is-there-a-noun-for-a-small-but-very-useful-thing/364759#364759) ('gadget'; 'gizmo') was closed.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest **gadgets**. Gadgets are functional items.